# btnClose is set to CausesValidation = false but not working

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a close button on my form that I've set to `CausesValidation = false`. But when I run it and try to close it with ErrorProvider in effect it won't let me close. I've even tried adding to the close routine `errorProvider1.Clear()` or `errorProvider1.Dispose() but` still no luck closing the form until I take care of the error.

What I have found to work is in the close if I loop over all the controls and set `CausesValidation=false` then it works as expected by closing the form despite any errors present.

```
   private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!this.ValidateChildren()) return;

        DoAddCommand();
    }

    private void DoAddCommand()
    {
        //input
        string input1 = textBox1.Text;
        string input2 = textBox2.Text;
        //process
        this.ValidateChildren();
        decimal sum = Class1.Add(input1, input2);

        //output
        lblSum.Text = sum.ToString();
    }

    private void textBoxNumberEntry_Validating(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox textBox = sender as TextBox;
        decimal number1 = 0;

        try
        {
            number1 = decimal.Parse(textBox.Text);
            errorProvider1.Clear();
        }
        catch (FormatException)
        {
            errorProvider1.SetError(textBox, "Enter a valid number");
            e.Cancel = true;
        }
    }

    private void btnClose_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (Control item in this.Controls)
        {
            item.CausesValidation = false;
        }
        this.Close();
    }
```

Answer (score 14):

Try adding those two attributes in your `asp:Button` tag

```
CausesValidation="false"

UseSubmitBehavior="false"
```

The `CauseValidation` should be enough, but I believe because you have a server side `OnCLick` event you also need to specify the SubmitBehavior.

Mario

Comment: -1 The question is about Windows Forms, not ASP.NET.

Comment: Even though the original question was in terms of Windows Forms I found this solution helpful for similar situations in ASP.NET.

Comment: That's what I was looking for. Thanks for the explanation on why the UseSubmitBehavior attribute is needed. I didn't know that.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely what is happening is that one of the TextBoxes have the focus at the time you try to hit the Cancel button, so the validation is already occurring.  Your solution works by going through the controls and setting the the CausesValidation property back to False.

A short-cut method is to just turn off the form's AutoValidate property:

```
private void btnClose_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  this.AutoValidate = AutoValidate.Disable;
  this.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A similar problem led me here: in my case the parent control of the button (in my case a Panel) had CausesValidation set to true; setting it to false allowed the button's click to be triggered without validation.

Answer (score 1):

The most effective way to deal with this, in my experience, is to set the ValidationGroup on the control to a validation group name that doesn't exist.

** This is hacky, so YMMV **

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="DoSomethingButton" runat="server"
    ValidationGroup="NonExistent" 
    OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to do something?');" 
    Text="Do something" 
    OnClick="DoSomething_Click">
</asp:LinkButton>
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone going mad on this, I had the same issue just now.
Just set the button to use: data-validate-target="none"

data-validate-target is the tag your looking for on aspx validation controls such as required etc that trigger on the client side as soon as the box looses focus.

Now working for me.

Answer (score 0):

The only option that worked perfectly at least on edge, chrome and Opera was USING ONLY the parameter formNoValidate="false"

I'm using VS 2022 community Edition, but it doesn't offers me such option, but looking for solutions and using EDGE's DEVTools, I found the option formNoValidate with the help of the intellisense.

Then I went back to VS and added the option like in this button:

<asp:Button ID="bHistory" runat="server" Text="Get Your last data" OnClick="bHistory_Click" formNoValidate="false" />